# ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID in windows Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created simple MVC4 website for windows Azure by following this tutorial: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/

At step-8, where I am supposed to "Validate Connection", I get an ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID error.

Editor: Visual Studio 2012 (Winsows Azure tools SP1)
OS: Windows 7

Tried restarting Studio and restarting computer options. Also tried recreating website in manage.windowsazure.com

**Logs:**

Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://waws-prod-bay-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=trackme ...
2>Starting Web deployment task from source: manifest(C:\.SourceManifest.xml) to Destination: auto().

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4377,5): Error ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID: Web deployment task failed. ( Could not connect to the remote computer ("waws-prod-bay-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.)

Comment: There are issues with WebDeploy from time to time. Note that this is still in preview. I've been seeing those errors from time to time recently. If you wait a couple of minutes (probably up to half an hour) it shall work. Or just use the FRP deploy temporary.

Answer (score 2):

As your publish from VS is not completed due to this error, there are couple of things which could go wrong.

Based on error info it seems the connection to Windows Azure Websites deployment server was unsuccessful. I just pinged the waws-prod-bay-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net deployment server and got the IP address so would you please check and verify if you get the same. Also you may need to verify that there are no networking issue which could cause this problem.

Also if you have SQL Database configured with your publish profile then there are two servers needs to be connected during deployment. So if this error occurred when you have had SQL Database configured or before that?  Sometime this error is sporadic so you may have to consider as well.

Answer (score 1):

If web deploy fails, publish using FTP. You can download publish settings for you site from Azure portal, under dashboard, click "Download the publish profile". In Visual Studio, when you publish, select Profile, and then Import. Import the settings file. Then unselect the Web Deploy and select the FTP deploy. This worked for me when Web Deploy refused to work (even with the downloaded web deploy settings).

Comment: Amazing. 10 years on from the original question, this 8-year-old solution still worked for me :)